# Is it a good idea to enlarge LGA chip pads for hand soldering?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I'm designing a board where I'm using an LGA-14 and a WSON-12 chip. Is it a good idea to make the pads bigger, so I can use a soldering iron to apply solder to the pads, place the chips, then reflow the solder with the iron from the exposing bigger pads? Are there any risks doing this?

(I will have a stencil, but I don't have hot air, or reflow oven)

[image: PCB layout image]

Comment: Hobby or for work?  If at home have you considered reflow skillet?  https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/59  It works :)

Comment: It's for my master final project so it can be considered as a hobby :) I tought about that option - the skillet, but I wanted to have the option to hand solder it with an iron for safety's sake.

Comment: Making them longer outwards can be helpful to hand solder and inspect visually, making them thicker can increase the chance of solder bridges/shorts.

Comment: I can see having an issue getting the center pad to reflow, and a high probability of a cold solder joint there.

Comment: That central pad will be impossible to hand-soldered without a hot air soldering station.

Comment: I soldered the whole PCB with a simple hot plate I bought for ~30$. It seems a very consistent technique, I already did 2 boards and planning to do 3 more. The only problem is that the cooling time of the plate is very long, and there are only a small place where the heat is consistent. So you have to wait like ~1 hour between each PCB.